# Printable sketch templates for Android phones

Tags: android, wireframe, mockup, sketching

Can you recommend a printable sketch template ("idea sheet"/6up) for Android phones?
  
Preferably, the template should contain several real-size screens to sketch on.
 
[Here's what I'm using for iPhone](http://lab.3fl.jp/iphone-idea-sheet-v01/), and would like to get something similar for Android.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a software recommendation request.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I think you misunderstood the question. Yosef is not asking for software at all.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 He is looking for templates that he can print off - this is a software request. The answers to this question are unlikely to be valid in 12 months time.

Comment: @AndrewMartin the accepted answer lists printable PDF's. How is that software?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 PDFs are digital files: software. The point, however, is that this forum should form a standing repository of knowledge for UX and not for transitory sources of files.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I get the point, I was seriously interested in why a PDF was software. I have never heard of this and will be looking into the terminology of 'software'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Android Stencil kit](http://www.uistencils.com/products/android-stencil-kit)

[Android Wireframe Template (printable PDF)](http://gliderguns.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/android_wireframe_templates3.pdf)

[A Collection of Printable Sketch Templates and Sketch Books for Wireframing](http://www.geekchix.org/blog/2010/01/03/a-collection-of-printable-sketch-templates-and-sketch-books-for-wireframing/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a device-art wireframing stencil in SVG form for handsets and tablets, from the [Designing Effective Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/) article in Android Training:

- [Android Device Wireframe Art (SVG)](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/example-wireframe-device-template.svg)

Answer (score 2):

Interface Sketch has some of the best (and most) around:

http://www.interfacesketch.com/